# Where is my mistake in this reasoning?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

One can vertify that $1+\frac{1}{2}z^2+\frac{1}{2}z^3$ has no root in the disk $D(0,1.05)$, so $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}z^2+\frac{1}{2}z^3}$ should be analytic in $D(0,1.05)$. Assume it has Taylor series: $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n,z\in D(0,1.05)$$

On the other hand, note that when $z\in D(0,1)$ , $\frac{1}{2}z^2+\frac{1}{2}z^3\in D(0,1)$ . Since $\dfrac{1}{1+w}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-w)^n,w\in D(0,1)$ , we also obtain $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{2}z^2-\frac{1}{2}z^3\right)^n,z\in D(0,1)\subset D(0,1.05)$$

In $D(0,1)$ , the two series equal to each other, so they should have the same corresponding coefficients. Therefore they should also have the same convergence radius $R$ . By the first series, $R\geq 1.05$ . However, the second series is not convergent at $z=1$, thus $R\leq 1$ . There is a contradiction!

Comment: One of these series is a Taylor series and the other is not. I don't see how they can be said to "have the same corresponding coefficients."

Comment: Why do you think the second series is not convergent at $z=1$? In any case, your second function is not defined at $z=1$

Comment: @DavidK The second one is a power series, right? You can check its partial sum. Power series always has its convergence radius, right?

Comment: @Vasili That's what I mean. You see, the second series is a power series, so it should always has a convergence radius. Moreover, it should equal to the convergence radius of the first power series. However, the second series is not even defined at z=1.

Comment: Certainly you can check its partial sums, and its $k$th partial sum will be different from the $k$th partial sum of the Taylor series. The second series is a power series in $-w = -\frac12z^2-\frac12z^3$ instead of $z$, so naturally we would expect it to have different coefficients in order to arrive at the same sum.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you! I think now I understand what you mean.

Comment: One can express second series in terms of $z$: $\sum_ {n = 0}^{\infty}\left( \sum_{k=\lceil\frac{n}3\rceil}^{\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor} {k\choose 3k-n} \left(-\frac12\right)^k\right) z^n$. This series converges at $z=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have here two different series. We have that series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ converges in $z=\frac 12,$ but if we do this
$$1+\frac 12+\frac 14+ \dots = 1+(1-\frac 12) + (1-\frac 34)+(1-\frac 78) 
= 2 - \frac 12 + 2 - (\frac 34 + \frac 78) + 2 +\dots.$$ Then we lose convergentity of the series, because every odd term is equal 2($a_n \not\to 0$).
That is what you have here.
You have series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n,$ then you write $a_n$ in some weird way and sum it in some weird way and you asking yourself why did i lose convergence of series.